Is there a statistical means of determining how much of a company's growth can be attributed to general market growth vs individual "right decisions"?
Imagine you had a trucking company. It grew precipitously over the past 50 years -- coincident with an increase in the overall US population and as well as domestic personal expenditure. Would there be any way to use reverse regression analysis (or a similar tool) to determine how much of that company's success was due to an overall growth in the industry vs "smart decisions" by the company's leaders?
The problem in directly comparing the growth of the company to the growth of the industry is that the company itself is a part of the industry you are comparing it to.
